# Where does git rebase make changes

Tags: git, git-rebase

The git documentation is not clear enough about this, yet everybody on the internet seems to know it.

Say, I'm currently on a feature branch called `feature/test`. If I do `git rebase master`, where is the rebase performed? On the feature branch or on the master branch? Ie. which one is being changed? Does it have the same syntax as `git merge` in the way that the current branch is altered? In that case, would I have to go back to `master` and do a merge with my feature branch?

Edit: what I want to do is to "merge" (in this case rebase) the `master` branch into my feature branch, and then "merge" the feature branch back into master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you rebase your `feature/test` on `master` the `feature/test` branch is changed. E.g.

```
           master
           |
           V
A----B-----C
      \
       D----E
            ^
            |
            feature/test
```

After doing

```
git checkout feature/test
git rebase master
```

your repo will look like this

```
            master
            |
            V
 A----B-----C----D'----E'
                       ^
                       |
                       feature/test
```

Note that `D'` != `D`, because it has a new parent now. Nevertheless it contains the same changes.

**EDIT:**

> And how would I take the changes from feature/test back into master?

Since `feature/test` is in line with master git will just fast forward the master branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge feature/test
```

will result in

```
                       master
                       |
                       V
 A----B-----C----D'----E'
                       ^
                       |
                       feature/test
```

See [Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) for details

Comment: And how would I take the changes from `feature/test` back into master? Would it be safe to do a simple merge, or would I have to do a rebase there aswell, in order to keep the project history?

Comment: You can safely merge onto master, as there obviously won't be any conflicts since you just built upon the current state.